# jQuery Cycle - How can I use 'scrollHorz' Transition (including back/next navigation) with Custom Opacity Effects?

Tags: jquery, navigation, slideshow

hope you can help. I'm using cycle plugin for a slideshow and want something like the fx: 'scrollHorz' to make slides move left/right when next/back buttons are pressed respectively.

Basic demo here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html

However, I've had to use fx: 'custom' as I've introduced my own opacity effects. So now, I've lost the left/right slide movement!

Can someone please help me enable slides to scroll left (i.e. enter from right side) for next button and scroll right (i.e. enter from left side) for back button, whilst keeping my opacity effects? I've managed to get the slides to move from right to left on clicking '#nextArrow' but I want the direction to reverse when '#prevArrow' is pressed.

Current code for Cycle plug-in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshowframe').cycle({
        fx: 'custom',
        timeout:0,      // setting for manual slideshow 
        speed:750,      // number of milliseconds between each transition
        next:   '#nextArrow', 
        prev:   '#prevArrow',
        cssBefore: {  
                top:  0, 
                    left: 1051,
                opacity: 0,
                display: 'block' 
        },

        animIn:  {  left: 0,
                opacity: 1
        },

        animOut: {  
                left: -1051,
                opacity: 0
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `fx:'custom'` with `fx:'scrollHorz'`

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html

and you must add the property `rev: 0,`.

Here's an example: [jsfiddle.net/7SQsX/21](http://jsfiddle.net/7SQsX/21)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I'm aware of 'scrollHorz' but do you how I can add opacity effects? I'd like the images to fade in/out as they move in/out of the frame.

Comment: Thanks Vlad that 'rev' property is exactly what I was looking for.